# Scraping the last tweets of a selected user

Tags: r, twitter

I'm using the function `searchTwitter` of package `twitteR` to retrieve any authorized tweets which match the search criteria. My question is: Is it possible to scrape the tweets that a selected user posted in the last week? E.g., I would like to download the last tweets of @CNN user.

Comment: Yes, you would use a search syntax in the form `from:CNN since:2020-05-05`

Comment: @AndyPiper, thank you. But I obtained `Error in searchTwitter object 'from' not found`

Comment: As I understand it, twitteR is generally less well-supported these days than rTweet, and I hadn't checked the syntax. In twitteR I think you will need to put `from:CNN` into the search string itself. In rTweet, you would use a regular Twitter search query and include both the date and the search string inside the query.

Comment: @AndyPiper I'm trying to use rTweet just now. Thank you for your suggestion! But I can't find a way (in rTweet) to answer my original question.

Comment: So putting that original string `from:CNN since:2020-05-05` into the q parameter for rTweet is not working? What's the error?

Comment: @AndyPiper, thank you! I did not understand correctly, but your solution works. If you like, convert your comment into an answer.